# Create date-time index in R xts

Tags: r, time, time-series, xts

I want to create date-time index for my xts time series.

I am starting with a date in this format:

[image]

I cant share with you my entire dataset but basically what I am doing is:

```
data$date <- strptime(data$date, 
                                  format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%OS",
                                  tz = "GMT")
```

and later

```
EURGBP.xts <- xts(EURGBP[,-1], 
                        EURGBP$date, 
                        tzone = "GMT")
```

When I do this in my date time index I have something like this (Index on the left, column I am modifying to create index is on the right:

[image]

Why do I have this strange X at the beginning? What may be the reason for that? Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

My initial date format looks like this:

```
                   date
1 20170922 00:00:00.067
2 20170922 00:00:04.582
```

Comment: use dput(head(my_data, 10)) to supply us with the first 10 records of your data.  Pictures are not a good way to show us your data. Btw your date time in the first picture is different from what you are showing in the second picture.

Comment: I know because first you have my initial data form after those two lines of code I am left with index that looks like on the screenshot. I know date time is different however it is just an example

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your issue. If I use `strptime` with microseconds and next create an xts object, my index looks fine.

Comment: @phiver using identical commands as mine on data on on identical format as mine?

Comment: yes, identical commands and using your initial date format.

Comment: I need to verify that. Did you even hear about errors of this type ever?

Comment: I have redone I am still receiving this bizarre output.